# Why is the sort() method not working? Is there another alternative to this problem?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm currently writing the code that sorts the specific elements of a 3d array to ascending order in a single line but the sort method isn't working or maybe I just didn't do it right.

Here's the full code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number of Table/s");
        int tTable = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of Row/s");
        int tRow = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of Column/s");
        int tColumn = in.nextInt();

        int[][][] array = new int[tTable][tRow][tColumn];

        for (int i = 0; i < tTable ; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < tRow ; j++)
                for (int z = 0; z < tColumn  ; z++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter value of index [" + i + "][" + j + "][" + z + "]: ");
                    array [i][j][z] = in.nextInt();
                }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.print("ORIGINAL VALUE: ");
        for ( int i = 0; i < tRow; i++) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < tColumn; j++)
                for (int z = 0; z < tColumn  ; z++){
                System.out.print(array[i][j][z] + " ");
                }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("SORTED VALUE: ");
        for(int[][] set : array)
            for(int []set2 : set)
                for(int var : set2){
                    System.out.print(Arrays.sort(var) + " ");
                }
    }
}
```

Here's the part where I'm having a problem at. A friend suggested I make it a 1d array first so I did but what do you guys think?

```
 System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("SORTED VALUE: ");
        for(int[][] set : array)
            for(int []set2 : set)
                for(int var : set2){
                    System.out.print(Arrays.sort(var) + " ");
                }
```

Comment: `var` is just an int. Not an array, so it cannot be sorted. Remove the third loop? You don't need a loop to sort one list

Comment: Please add an example for input, expected output and received output

Comment: As an aside, I would *strongly* advise you to use braces for all loops, even if the body is only a single statement.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays.sort() method donot returning anything
so System.out.print(Arrays.sort(var) + " "); is not right you can try

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<a[0].length;j++)
        {
          Arrays.sort(a[i][j]);
            for(int k=0;k<a[0][0].length;k++)
            {
                
               System.out.print(a[i][j][k]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

in this way, first of all you can visit at array of reference variable of array of reference variable then you can sort that array of reference variable than you can print it on console.

you are console the Array.sort(arr) method having built-in method of java.util.Arrays having no return type , it sort the original array